# Creating an Apple Watch Music Remote App

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, apple-watch, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm trying to create a music remote companion app on Apple Watch.

According to Apple's documentation if you're using MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to show the now playing track on the lockscreen this should be synchronizing automatically to the apple watch app and showing the data in the glance screen on it's own.

1) I'm unable to test this on the apple watch simulator, the app just shows the default glance screen from the storyboard, I tried deleting the Glance Controller from the storyboard, it ended up showing the Watch App Controller instead.

2) I'm trying to retrieve the now playing data in the Watch App Controller using [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo but it just returns nil.

The reason I'm trying to rely on MPNowPlayingInfoCenter is to avoid progress indicator syncronization issues that I would be facing when using regular app to watch interaction methods.

Comment: Haven't done any watch development yet but the simulator doesn't support any of the music stuff for the phone so it's probably the same for the watch. I think you might need an actual watch to test this stuff.

Comment: True, the simulator doesn't support the remote control events, but it does support MPNowPlayingInfoCenter data and it does show the currently playing track so that's why I was expecting it to show in the watch simulator too.